# How to display a title and image on UIToolbar simultaneously

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Hey i want to display a Title and Image simultaneously on UIToolbar can any one help.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put the image from the interface buider. And to display a title below it create an IBOutlet for that UItoolBarButton and give buttonname.title = @"name";