# iPhone - UIToolbarButton with Text and symbol characters

Tags: iphone, text, special-characters, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

How may I puy into a UIToolbarButton a custom picture characters (like the bookmark one) followed by some text ?

Comment: May be this question might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644606/how-to-display-a-title-and-image-on-uitoolbar-simultaneously

Answer (score 2):

Create a `UIView` and drop a `UIImage` and `UITextView` (or `UILabel`) on the view. Then add the view to the toolbarbutton.

Answer (score 0):

To have an image and text for your toolbar button ( I think that's your question)
I create a tabBarItem property and alloc init it in a "setup" method. In awakeFromNib I call the "setup" method. Be sure to have your image that you use in your supporting files folder
This is how I do it:

```
@interface YourViewController : UIViewController {

}
@property (retain) UITabBarItem *tabBarItem;
-(void)setup;
@end

@implementation YourViewController
@synthesize tabBarItem;

-(void) setup{
UITabBarItem *item = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"theTitleYouWant" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage.png"] tag:0];
self.tabBarItem = item;
[item release];
}
@end
```